# Wrong redirection of url

Tags: redirect-url

Magento redirecting the page url to the home page when i am clicking from outside. if you click [here](http://whiteboardsnz.com/porcelain-whiteboards-3.html) ,it will redirect to home page the link is http://whiteboardsnz.com/porcelain-whiteboards-3.html but when i am clicking in website it is working correctly.

Comment: Can you provide anything like an error report or some hint as to what it can be? This is hard to reproduce or solve

Comment: There is no error showing in error log but i think something is disabled so it is redirecting to home page when i am going from outside.

Comment: I don't know why question is put on hold... Can you click on the above link what i have provided?? .. It will redirect to home page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a redirect set up from `domain.com` to **`www.`**`domain.com`. This results in anything you type as a request path (`http://domain.com/something/something`) to be redirected to the homepage, but then with `www.` in front of it (`http://www.domain.com`).

If this was done by `.htaccess` rewrite rules then there are solutions for that to keep the request path with the redirect. You should look that up somewhere (for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/23493430/1306684). This Magento SE is not the place for `.htaccess` rewrite questions...

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Will let you know on Monday either it will work or not.